# ElasticSearchRepository null query ot working

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have Review document

```
@Document(indexName = "apkreview")
public class ApkReview {

    @Id //The unique id
    private Long id;
    
    private Long apkId;
    
    private String comment;

    private Date commentDate;

    //each review is linked to one user
    private  String appUserId;
    
    @Transient
    @JsonProperty
    private String username;
    
    //app user stars
    private int stars;
    
    private String response;
    
    private Date responseDate;
}
```

I want to count all reviews by apkId where comments are not null

In my repository i did this:

```
int countByApkIdAndCommentIsNotNull(Long apkId);
```

I got this error :

> {"status":"ERROR","httpCode":500,"message":"Illegal criteria found
> 'IS_NOT_NULL (0): [IsNotNull, NotNull]'.","stackTrace":null}

Please why this code is not working ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently *IsNotNull* (or *Exists*)  are not supported by Spring Data Elasticsearch. You can check the supported keywords [in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#elasticsearch.query-methods.criterions).

Feel free to create [an issue in Jira](https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAES/issues) to have this added.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I decided to do something like this `int countByApkIdAndCommentNot(Long apkId, String comment);`and call it with comment field value = null, but still can't ge the correct result. I tried with comment = "", same thing. In Kibana when there are no comment, kibana shows null, but why can't I use comment = null ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it like this:

```
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("apkId", apkId)
                .operator(Operator.AND))
        .withQuery(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("comment"))
        .build();

Page<ApkReview> apkList = apkReviewRepository.search(searchQuery);

// count apk review with comment
int reviewWithNoteNumber = (int) apkList.getTotalElements();
```